# rbenv installed ruby 2.1.2 cannot load such file -- zlib on MAC OSX 10.9.2

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

I'm install ruby 2.1.2 via rbenv, and rbenv is installed by homebrew on my MAC OSX 10.9.2, ruby global is successful set to 2.1.2, but when i try to run gem install, get some errors below.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ user1$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

How to solve it, does anyone faced same problems before?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the zlib development headers.

```
xcode-select --install
```

In OS X 10.9, the command line developer tools are now installed on demand. So after running this also zlib and zlib-devel should be available.