# Install compass on mac osx 10.12.6

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rubygems, zlib

**UPDATE**

I also have run

```
ruby -rzlib -e0
```

and I get this

```
/Users/bertuka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- zlib (LoadError)
    from /Users/bertuka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

It seems as if I had a version installed inside another version, but I do not know how to solve it

I tried to uninstall Ruby version 2.4.2 and reinstall it, but I still get the same error

---

**FIRST MESSAGE**

I am trying to install compass on my mac to use GRUNT.

When I type the following line on terminal

```
sudo gem install compass
```

an error appears

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I have ruby installed

```
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

and I tried to run the following command as I see on [rbenv installed ruby 2.1.2 cannot load such file -- zlib on MAC OSX 10.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781657/rbenv-installed-ruby-2-1-2-cannot-load-such-file-zlib-on-mac-osx-10-9-2)

```
xcode-select --install
```

But it seems that I already have it installed

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

I don't now how to install zlib and compass correctly to avoid errors.

Sorry for my english, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most places similar errors have happened previously (ex. https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/573) people have suggested either uninstalling and reinstalling XCode:

See: [Xcode 6.1 - How to uninstall command line tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438457/xcode-6-1-how-to-uninstall-command-line-tools)

or uninstalling and reinstall homebrew:

See: [What is the best/safest way to reinstall Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038028/what-is-the-best-safest-way-to-reinstall-homebrew)

You may also have to start a new terminal between changes to your ruby installation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have installed xcode three times and also command line tools. I've also reinstalled the homebrew, I do not know what else I can do.

Comment: What method are you using for ruby install? Is it rbenv? have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling ruby? Can you give the output of `which ruby` and `which zlib` showing the paths to the tools? Perhaps installing zlib from homebrew will help this situation `brew install zlib`