# Getting hard time installing Ruby on mac

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

I am trying to install Ruby on my mac and that too the latest version but having trouble.

The pre-installed ruby on mac is of verion `2.0` however, I need to upgrade the same to latest.

I tried installing ruby with `Homebrew` like `brew install ruby` but whenever i check the version, it shows me the earlier version only. Refer Terminal screenshot:

[image]

Am trying to learn ruby  but this thing got me stuck for long.

Have also tried another package manager `rbenv` and did `rbenv install 2.5.1` but that failed with the following error I have no idea about

```
The Ruby zlib extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/vshukla/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1
  --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
  CC=clang
  CFLAGS= -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32 
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/vshukla/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib 
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/vshukla/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/include
```

Please guide.

Comment: Ok, this comment is opinion based :) I suggest you to stick with Homebrew and rvm. Try follow this guide: https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rbenv installed ruby 2.1.2 cannot load such file -- zlib on MAC OSX 10.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781657/rbenv-installed-ruby-2-1-2-cannot-load-such-file-zlib-on-mac-osx-10-9-2)

Answer (score 3):

Homebrew has correctly installed the last version of ruby in `/usr/local/bin`. You can check it with:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby --version
```

The macOS version of ruby is installed in `/usr/bin`. You can check it with:

```
/usr/bin/ruby --version
```

If you want to always run the Homebrew versions of installed tools, you have to put `/use/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` environment variable. You can do this by adding the following line in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

P.S.: According to your macos ruby version, you don't have the last macOS version.

Answer (score 0):

The compile error log contains:

> The Ruby zlib extension was not compiled.
>
> ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions

Try installing "zlib" and then try again, by running:

```
brew install zlib
```